# Why $.ajax execute function properties in "data: {}" while sending the request to the server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have noticed that if you send a JQuery $.ajax call to the server like :

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "test",
    data: {
        test1: getTest1,
        test2: getTest2
    }
});

function getTest1() {
    return "test 1";
}

function getTest2() {
    return 2;
}
```

The query string in the request looks like

> test1=test%201&test2=2

=> the properties test1 and test2 are executed.

This is really convenient in my case but I would like to understand how ?
I could not find an answer in the JQuery documentation about this behavior.

Could someone explain why it is happening ?

Comment: I'm not certain how it happens, but you can check the source of jQuery to see what processes [`$.ajax()`](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.ajax) goes through. It looks like it's something which [`$.param`](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.param) adds through the `buildParams` function

Comment: I don't this is AJAX specific or jQuery specific feature. It is just a simple case of using function as a parameter during the data definition.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I think you're right. $.param is used to convert the data if it is not a string. As it is written in [`$.param`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) documentation : "As of jQuery 1.3, the return value of a function is used instead of the function as a String."